# Blazor WASM repeatable RenderFragment for similar EditForm properties

Tags: c#, html, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am creating a large html form (using the EditForm tag) in my Blazor WASM app, containing many properties. Mostly all of which follow an identical pattern of a label, an input, and a validation section. I would like to create a render fragment that would let me cut down on my mark up. I am struggling with how to reference the "bind-Value" for the correct property.

Here is the start of the edit form, which has a model called registerModel with many properties, including string "Company" representing "Company Name"

```html
<EditForm autocomplete="off" Model="@registerModel" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidRegisterSubmit">
```

This is an example of a single section for the company name part, of which there are many in the form for all the individual properties:

```html
<div class="row mb-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>
            Company Name
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 p-0">
        <InputText @bind-Value="registerModel.Company" type="text" placeholder="Enter Company Name"
                   class="rounded-input form-control"
                   id="Last"
                   autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <ValidationMessage For="() => registerModel.Company"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a render fragment function to automate creating each form section so I don't have to repeat so much html, and I can make my component more reusable. This is what I have tried so far

```html
   RenderFragment<( 
        EventCallback<string> eventCallback,
        Expression<Func<string>> func, 
        string id,
        string label,
        string placeholder)> RenderFieldSection = (item) => __builder =>
        {
        <div class="row mb-3 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <label>@item.label</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 p-0">

                <InputText @bind-Value="@item.eventCallback" type="text" placeholder="@item.placeholder"
                           class="rounded-input form-control"
                           id="@item.id"
                           autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <ValidationMessage For="@item.func"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    };
```

Which I am trying to call in the markup with:

```html
@RenderFieldSection((
    eventCallback: EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, s => { registerModel.Company = s;}),
        func:()=> registerModel.Company,
        id: "Company",
        label:Translate("CompanyNameLabel"),
        placeholder:Translate("CompanyNamePlaceholder")
    )
    )
```

Everything works except the input @bind-Value="@item.eventCallback" part, which is supposed to take an `EventCallback<string>`. This gives the following error.

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

I guess I am constructing the event callback wrongly, but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas? I expect I could do it by finding the property via reflection, but I (naively?) wonder if I can avoid the overhead of that.